# What does this C code mean? Arrays and pointer variables

Tags: c, arrays

So I am instructed to write a function that uses the following prototype:

```
double stats(int *array, int size, double *std_dev);
```

The function should return the average value of the array. The argument std_dev is passed by reference so that the standard deviation of the data in the array can be returned. I assume this to mean that I need to calculate standard deviation as well.

I set about this in the following manner:

```
double stats(int *array, int size, double *std_dev){
    int sum = 0;                //declare int to hold sum
    int i;                              //index used in for-loops
    for (i = size; i>0; i--){       // for every element(i)
        sum += array[i];    //add array element to 
    }

    int mean = sum/size; 

    for (i = size; i>0; i--){       // for every element(i)
        sum += array[i] -mean;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles; but I'm not quite sure if these lines actually do what I think they do, and I don't have parameters to test with:

```
sum += array[i];    //add array element to 

sum += array[i] -mean;
```

I know that "array" is a pointer variable, but I'm not exactly sure what it is my code is actually doing, can someone please tell me what these lines actually do? Thanks.

EDIT: I am aware that this code does not completely satisfy my objective, it is a WIP that compiles.

EDIT EDIT: That includes the logical correctness of my program.

Comment: `array[i]` is the i-th element of the array i.e. the element in i-th location from start index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you do this

```
sum += array[i];
```

you are iterating through every element of the array - i.e., element at each index and storing the result in the variable `sum`.

`a[i]` is the ith element of the array `a`. It can be thought of as `*(a+i)`.

Similarly in the second loop, you are adding up `a[i] - sum` to the variable `sum`. I think you are trying to compute the standard deviation in the second loop in which case you need to sum `(a[i] - mean)^2` (i.e, square of difference from the mean) into the variable std_dev and then divide by `size`.

Comment: "`a[i] - mean^2`" o0 I guess you meant mean in power of 2 and not xor 2 right ?

Comment: @Roma-MT Yes! I mean power of 2

Comment: Thanks, that was more of what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

you have problems in your `for`: 
you will never get to array[0] which is the first element in array
use `for(i=0;i<size;i++)`as for your question
`sum +=array[i];` will put in variable `sum` the result of `sum + array[i]`

`sum += array[i] -mean;` will put in `sum`the result of `array - mean`

BTW I have no idea what are you doing in second `for` loop (mathematically)
but if you don't want to use previous sum which contain the sum of all the array then you
should to set `sum` to 0 before you run the second for.

BTW, you returning 0
don't you want to return your average which is `return mean;` in your case ?
in function prototype it says function should return `double`
what you've done is `int mean = sum/size;` is an integer value that will cut the numbers after the "."
you probably want to use `double mean = sum/size;` 
and then to return it as I have mentioned before.

Comment: I know there are problems in the for, I only cared about correct syntax for the moment; and I knew what the += means, that's why I used them, I was just unsure specifically about the array[], because it is a pointer and not an array ( per say). From what I understand the [x] just indicates that you're accessing the address at an offset +x from the array start address. Is this right?

Comment: Correct .
but you can to relate to it as an array in this case .
and yes a[i]; = *(a+i);address of a + an offset .